# Ошибка при запуске Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

Поставил для работы убунту второй системой рядом с виндой.
Обнаружил, что после работы под убунтой, когда запускаю винду, то сбрасывается время. Пошарил в инете, нашел способ решить проблему - в винде в реестр добавил параметр RealTimeIsUniversal. После чего при запуске убунты вместо привычного экрана загрузки появляется консоль с логами, где видно несколько раз ошибку:

```
Failed to start Network Time Synchronization
```

В винде из реестра удалил этот параметр и откатил все назад, но проблема не решилась.
Зашел в GRUB, но там под рутом разрешено только чтение, поэтому выполнить команду:

```
sudo apt install libnss-systemd
```

нет возможности. Please, help!

Comment: Сбрасывается на ноль (т.е. 1.1.1970) или просто отстает на час-другой?

Comment: отстает на несколько часов. но с этим я готов смириться, главное сейчас починить убунту

Comment: Попробуйте ``timedatectl set-local-rtc 1``.

Comment: спасибо, попробую, как дома буду. но чувствую, что не выполнится, ибо разрешено только чтение

Comment: Это к грубу не относится, это говорит линуксу, что время биоса (берется системой при загрузке) - местное, а не UTC, как он думает по умолчанию и подстраивает время системы с учетом часового пояса.

Comment: Тогда у меня есть все шансы победить)

Comment: Выдает ошибку Failed to create bus connection: no such file or directory

Comment: а в  bios дату не проверял? возможно не время а дата уплыла. потому что отставание  часов никак не должно влиять на загрузку ОС, а вот дата может. а так root и другие важные разделы можно перемонтировать  в запись командой : mount -o remount, rw /

Comment: с датой все нормально, уплывало именно время на несколько часов назад
несколько дней входил в ОС через Atl+F2 и дальше startx, после чего ошибок при загрузке замечено больше не было, но все так же выводится лог загрузки и на каком-то моменте зависает - можно это как-то исправить? через Alt+F2 работает, если успеть нажать. Но оболочка, которая запускается через startx, отличается от той, на которой я работал изначально - хотелось бы исправить.